# Weird green tint on EditText after updating gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-edittext, android-gradle-plugin

I am seeing following green tint on active `EditText` in `Kitkat` after recent gradle update in Android Studio. 
[image]

Same edit text works fine in later android versions. Couldn't find any bug related to this.. any pointers ?

here is some xml for this field

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextLineColor" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Did you downloaded the latest preview 3 of android studio 2.2? Seems it introduced a little bug as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908232/android-studio-2-2-preview-3-layout-error

Comment: @LucaNicoletti yes